load data into postgres relational tables with liquibase
I have 2 relational tables in postgres, and with liquibase i need to insert data from csv files for each 2 tables, without hard-coding any id columns. My schema looks like
table1(
  id numeric,
  filed1 varchar,
  field2 varchar
)
table2(
  id numeric,
  table1_id numeric references table1.id,
  field3 varchar
)

The id columns are numeric, and each table has its own sequence generator which I cannot reference from the csv files nor put default on the table creation, so I will need to insert each table data into a temp table then move it to the actual table with
<sql>insert into table1 (id,field1,field2)
    select nextval('table1_sequence'), field1, field2 from table1_temp
</sql

The challange for me is when I insert into the table2, how can I refer to the parent table? Meaning how can I put the id of table1 into the table2.table1_id?

This ... each table has its own sequence generator  ... and this ... nor put default on the table creation... does not make sense. If the sequence is assigned to a table why cannot  it not be the DEFAULT for the id field in each table?

@AdrianKlaver The tables are already created and it is not an option to put a default on the columns, as we only need this for the test data. Anyway the issue is not not being able to assign values to the id columns of each table, but to be able to create the relation between table1 and table2

Unless the table2.table1_id <--> table1.id relationship was already established in the CSV files I don't see how you could create it later. Is there something inherent in the data that could be used to establish the relationship?

Here is the solution way shown below
1 ) XML format of the table shown below
<changeSet id="1" author="yourname">
    <!-- Create main tables -->
    <createTable tableName="table1">
        <column name="id" type="numeric" />
        <column name="field1" type="varchar(255)" />
        <column name="field2" type="varchar(255)" />
    </createTable>

    <createTable tableName="table2">
        <column name="id" type="numeric" />
        <column name="table1_id" type="numeric" />
        <column name="field3" type="varchar(255)" />
        <constraints foreignKeyName="fk_table2_table1" referencedTableName="table1" referencedColumnNames="id"/>
    </createTable>

    <!-- Create sequences for ID generation -->
    <createSequence sequenceName="table1_sequence"/>
    <createSequence sequenceName="table2_sequence"/>
</changeSet>

2 ) Here is the insert example shown below
<changeSet id="3" author="yourname">
    <!-- Mapping table to track generated IDs in table1 -->
    <createTable tableName="table1_mapping">
        <column name="temp_field1" type="varchar(255)" />
        <column name="new_id" type="numeric" />
    </createTable>

    <!-- Insert into table1 and store generated IDs in table1_mapping -->
    <sql>
        INSERT INTO table1 (id, field1, field2)
        SELECT nextval('table1_sequence'), field1, field2
        FROM table1_temp
        RETURNING field1, id INTO table1_mapping (temp_field1, new_id);
    </sql>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="4" author="yourname">
    <!-- Insert into table2 using IDs from table1_mapping -->
    <sql>
        INSERT INTO table2 (id, table1_id, field3)
        SELECT nextval('table2_sequence'), mapping.new_id, temp.field3
        FROM table2_temp temp
        JOIN table1_mapping mapping
        ON temp.table1_field1 = mapping.temp_field1;
    </sql>
</changeSet>

